# If statement for admin page

Tags: admin

How should I write `if` condition to display specific code only when I enter this page:

```
/wordpress/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=slideshow
```

This is what i was trying to get ;) Thanks to Krzysiek!

```
function plu_admin_enqueue($hook) {
  $screen = get_current_screen();

if ( 'post.php' == $hook && $screen->post_type == 'slideshow' ) {
      wp_enqueue_script('plupload-all');

      wp_register_script('cplupload', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cplupload.js', array('jquery'));
      wp_enqueue_script('cplupload');

      wp_register_style('cplupload', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/cplupload.css');
      wp_enqueue_style('cplupload');
  };
};

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'plu_admin_enqueue', 10 );
```

Comment: What code? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I think it's clear. He wants to detect if he's on that screen.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż : yes, but why? There are numerous obscure hooks on the backend that might work, if I knew exactly what the project was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`get_current_screen();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) to do this. It returns a [WP_Screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen) object.

You should remember that this function will return NULL if it's called before `admin_init` action.

In your case it should look like this:

```
$screen = get_current_screen();

if ( $screen && $screen->action == 'add'
    && $screen->base == 'post' && $screen->post_type == 'slideshow' ) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks @KrzysiekDróżdż - I'd love to learn my weak points. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to show a sub menu to the custom post types use the `add_submenu_page` for this.

Here is the example for your code

```
add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=slideshow','page_title','menu_title','capability','menu_slug','function_example');

function function_example ()
{
//here you put your code in order to apper in the sub menu

}
```

Hope this will help:)